# SQL Developer how do i set or compare a date column based on month

Tags: sql, date, monthcalendar

i have a query where i want to update the value based on orders made from a certain date
all the matters is just the month.

Update discount
set discount = 10
where pubdate = 'MAY';

ive tried a few date formats but i haven't found a clear way just to update the value based on month alone

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: What is the datatype of pubdate?

Comment: pubdates datatype is date

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```
Update discount
    set discount = 10 
    where pubdate >= '2020-05-01 and pubdate < '2020-06-01';
```

Of course, this interprets "May" as being "May this year".  And it assumes that your database supports standard date formats.

Comment: there are two rows that have dates in may from two different years that are pretty far apart. this is why i want to compare just the month to update both of their rows without effecting the others. pubdate is the column where the date is stored not an variable

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you could do this. Here is one that will work on SQL Server.

```
update discount
set discount = 10 
where datename(month, pubdate) = 'May'
```

Comment: what do you mean by datename?

Comment: [DATENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It would help if you would let us know what database system you are using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. And what version too.

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer. i am interacting with a premade table on a server.all the information is fictional.  i am not trying to compare system dates . the pubdate holds a 'dd-mm-yyyy' date format. i want to update table values based on a the date inside pub date(this is inside a view)

Answer (score 0):

the line to comapre just the day (in this case may) was

where extract(month from pubdate) = 5;